# Recording bandwidth usage of a legacy Java application

Tags: java, networking, cloud, bandwidth

I know that there are a lot of threads on monitoring and/or limiting network bandwidth usage, but none of them provide a satisfactory answer. Here is my problem:

I have a legacy java application which communicates to different servers (like HTTP and JMS). My application can also receive incoming HTTP requests as well. Now, this application is now supposed to be deployed in a cloud infrastructure to provide a SaaS model. The pricing model for the consumers is supposed to be based on the bandwidth flow in and out of the application.

So, we need to device a way to count the number of bytes flowing in and out of the application through all sources (basically, all sockets that are created). The code base is huge and uses third party communication libraries in certain cases so active code changes are not possible everywhere. Also, the application is a legacy java application supported on all platforms, the solution should be workable on all platforms as well. I dont want to use third party external monitoring tools to do the job. Instead, need to find a solution which can be baked into the system, **passively**, to get the job done.

What are the ways/options/solutions to get this done? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are "all platforms"? This is very important.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TCP proxy server which sits between your application and the rest of the system. As long as this proxy server is used via configuration, it will see every byte coming in and out of your application. This way to can count or limit it how you like.

Comment: This is good suggestion. But, in case of a SSL connection the proxy would not work well.

Comment: By TCP proxy, rather than a HTTP proxy, I mean you pass every block of data you read as is, you don't need to know what it contains.